# Windows 10の「アプリと機能」で「アンインストール」を使用不可にすると「変更」まで使用できなくなってしまう

Tags: windows

少し古いですが「InstallShield 2012」を使用し、「基本のMSIプロジェクト」でインストーラを作成しています。

プロパティマネージャーにて[ARPNOREMOVE]に"1"をセットしてインストーラを作成したのですが、そのインストーラを使ってプログラムをインストールすると、Windows 10の「アプリと機能」画面にて「アンインストール」に加えて、「変更」まで使用不可になってしまいます。

しかし、旧来のコントロールパネルの「プログラムと機能」画面では、プロパティで指定したとおり「アンインストール」だけが使用不可となり、「変更」は使用できるようになっています。

Windows 10の「アプリと機能」で、「アンインストール」のみを使用不可にし、「変更」は使用可とすることは可能でしょうか？

Comment: バージョン表記を見る限り "InstallShield 2012" は Windows 10 のリリース (2015年) よりも前のバージョンのようなので、確証は無いけど Windows 10 の仕様に対応できていない可能性があります。 / 有償で購入したものであるなら、製品サポートへの問い合わせも検討してください。

Answer (score 1):

InstallShieldはインストーラーの作成ツールであり、インストールされたアプリケーションは（InstallShieldによってではなく）Windowsが管理しています。そのため、InstallShieldの新旧はあまり関係がありません。Windows側のこの機能は [Windows Installer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/windows-installer-portal) としてドキュメントが公開されています。

プログラムと機能についても[Configuring Add/Remove Programs with Windows Installer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/configuring-add-remove-programs-with-windows-installer)で説明されています。質問文で触れられている[`ARPNOREMOVE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/arpnoremove)もそのままプロパティとして存在し、また変更についても同様に[`ARPNOMODIFY`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/arpnomodify)プロパティとなります。
ただし、いずれの説明においても特にWindows 10の挙動については言及されていません。

もし希望される動作をしている他のアプリケーションがありましたら、[Uninstall Registry Key](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/uninstall-registry-key)を確認してください。レジストリ値についても説明されており、どのような設定を行えばよいのか参考になると思います。
希望の条件を満たす他のアプリケーションが見つけられない場合は、そもそも実現できないのかもしれません。

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall 以下にある自アプリのサブキーの内容を確認したところ、NoRemove は「1」になっていましたが NoModify は存在していませんでした。